# Docker-Compose Postgres 5432 Bind: Address already in use error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, ports

Alright so I've been searching for 3-4 days now and I can't seem to find a solution to my error. I have found similar errors, and some that seemed to be describing my exact issue but none of the solutions worked.

I'm trying to get a simply postgres, express, node app up and running. I want to be able to run `docker-compose up -d` and have it build all of the images, volumes, etc. Then I will run a bash script that will seed my postgres db with data. However, I keep getting an error with the ports I'm using. I've removed all of my images, containers, and even reinstalled docker but I can't figure it out. I removed everything from my docker-compose except for the postgres and it still doesn't work.

```
version: '3'
  services:
   postgres:
    image: postgres:10.0
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
     - '5432:5432'
```

Then on my host machine I simply plan on running the following bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

host="postgres.dev"
adminUser="postgres"

psql -h $host -U $adminUser -c "select 1 from pg_database where datname = 'table_name';" | grep -q 1 || psql -h $host -U $adminUser -f ./"$(dirname $0)"/init-local-db.sql
```

I know that this approach should work since I'm patterning it after a work project...which works for them. But here's the error I get:

```
ERROR: for pg-db  Cannot start service postgres: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint pg-db (b3e5697cd563264250479682ec83d4a232d0d4bd679a787ad2089e944dda9e2f): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0Creating test-api ... done

ERROR: for postgres  Cannot start service postgres: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint pg-db (b3e5697cd563264250479682ec83d4a232d0d4bd679a787ad2089e944dda9e2f): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I know some people say to simply change the port number so `'5433:5432'` but my problem with this is that when you install postgres by default its port is 5432, and I know it's not necessary to change it(because the work project doesn't). Any thoughts?

**Update** (next morning):

Okay I still have no idea why the error popped up in the first place, as I used lsof -i tcp:5432 (along with netstat) and nothing came up as using that port. I put my computer in suspend mode and went to bed. In the morning I woke up, changed my postgres version to 9.6 to see if that was it, and everything worked. I then switched it back to postgres 10.0 and again everything worked. Hopefully it won't pop back up again, but I have no idea why it popped up in the first place.

Comment: Oh and I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm using docker 17.09.0-ce and docker-compose version 1.17.0-rc1, build a0f95af

Answer (score 39):

There is only one reason you may be getting this error. You have PostgreSQL installed on your local machine and it's running, occupying the port 5432.

You have the following options:

1. Disable (and remove from startup) PostgreSQL on your local machine. - Your  Docker Compose will run.

   ```
   sudo service postgresql stop

   sudo update-rc.d postgresql disable
   ```
2. Use a different port in docker-compose. There is nothing wrong with applying '5433:5432'. Other services of your docker-compose will connect to postgres by 5432 port. From your local machine you'll be able you address postgres by localhost:5433.

Comment: I know you can do that...but it adds extra steps for setting up postgres and I'm trying to keep the setup simple for my none techy clients that want to be able to build on their own machine and see the progress of my work.

Comment: Plus I used lsof and netstat to check the port and it showed it being unused. That was the strange thing about everything. So I should be able to map 5432 : 5432 since my host isn't using that port, and my container isn't using it for something else either. Everything started working this morning...see my update.

Comment: Very mysterious :) Anyways, glad to hear you got it working.

Comment: Thank you! I would've been lost if not for this answer!